# f# break function evaluation

Tags: time, f#, break

I have to minimize a quite complicate function. For the minimization I use the NonLinearProgram from the Extreme Optimization Library. Since there´s no way to find a global minimum, I use different startpoints and choose, then the "best minimum". My problem is there can be some startpoints, which evaluatin can take a very long time. Is there some general way in F# or some special method in Extreme Optimization, to stop the evaluation let´s say after 10 min and just give a list with [nan; nan; nan; nan; nan; nan] back?

```
let funcFindPara (startpoint:float list) func = 

    let nlp = new NonlinearProgram(6)

    // add the function
    nlp.ObjectiveFunction <- (fun x -> func x.[0] x.[1] x.[2] x.[3] x.[4] x.[5])

    // add lineare constraints
    nlp.AddLinearConstraint("a + d > 0", Vector.Create(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 1.0e-5, infinity) |> ignore
    nlp.AddLinearConstraint("c > 0", Vector.Create(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 1.0e-5, infinity) |> ignore
    nlp.AddLinearConstraint("d > 0", Vector.Create(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 1.0e-5, infinity) |> ignore
    nlp.AddLinearConstraint("gamma > 0", Vector.Create(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 1.0e-5, infinity) |> ignore
    nlp.AddLinearConstraint("0 < rho_infty <= 1", Vector.Create(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0e-5, 1.0) |> ignore

    // add nonlinear constrains 
    // gamma <= -ln(rho_infty)
    nlp.AddNonlinearConstraint((fun (x : Vector) -> x.[4] + log(x.[5])), ConstraintType.LessThanOrEqual, 0.0, (fun (x : Vector) -> fun (y : Vector) -> 
          y.[0] <- 0.0 
          y.[1] <- 0.0 
          y.[2] <- 0.0
          y.[3] <- 0.0
          y.[4] <- 1.0
          y.[5] <- 1.0 / x.[5]
          y
        )
    ) |> ignore

    // add starting point
    nlp.InitialGuess <- Vector.Create(startpoint.[0], startpoint.[1], startpoint.[2], startpoint.[3], startpoint.[4], startpoint.[5])

    // solve
    let solution = nlp.Solve()

    // return list with parameters
    List.init 6 (fun index -> solution.[index])
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, if it implements cooperative cancellation (for example, via Task Parallel Library -> `CancellationToken`) then it should be easy. Otherwise, as far as I know, it's near impossible to *safely* abort work in the same process.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the function with `async { }` and pass that to `RunSynchronously` along with a timeout:

```
let withTimeout f timeout defaultValue =
    try Async.RunSynchronously((async { return f() }), timeout)
    with :? System.TimeoutException -> defaultValue

let longFn() = 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    [1.0; 2.0; 3.0]

//Usage
withTimeout longFn 2000 [nan; nan; nan]
```